# Is there a way to index a tweet with Tweepy?

Tags: python, regex, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to script a Twitter bot that will respond to mentions that have equations in them. First, I got the mentions to work (it would respond to anyone who mentions it). Then, I tried to implement the math function which uses regex (I had already created this, it was just a means of integrating it into the main bot program).

**The Code for Mentions:**

```
import mathbotcreds as mtc
import logging
import re
import tweepy
from time import sleep as wait

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(mtc.CONSUMER_KEY, mtc.CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(mtc.ACCESS_TOKEN, mtc.ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True,
                 retry_count=2)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication Successful!")
except:
    print("Error during authentication! :(")
    
mentions = api.mentions_timeline()
pattern = r'([0-9]+.*[-+*/%].*[0-9]+)+' 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def check_mentions(api, since_id):
    logger.info("Collecting mentions... ")
    new_since_id = since_id
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline, since_id=since_id).items():
        new_since_id = max(tweet.id, new_since_id)
        
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
            continue
        
            api.update_status(
                status=f"Hello! \n\nIt worked! \nYay! ^-^ \n\n (You said: \"{tweet.text}\".)",
                in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id) 
        
    return new_since_id

def main():
    since_id = 1
    while True:
        since_id = check_mentions(api, since_id)
        logger.info("Waiting... ")
        wait(15) 
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("Running script... ")
    wait(1) 
    main()
    
# for m in mentions:
#     api.update_status(f"@{m.user.screen_name} Hello! \nYou said: \n{m.text}", m.id)
#     wait(15)
```

---

**The Code for Mentions *and* Equations Functions:**

```
import mathbotcreds as mtc
import logging
import re
import tweepy
from time import sleep as wait

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(mtc.CONSUMER_KEY, mtc.CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(mtc.ACCESS_TOKEN, mtc.ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True,
                 retry_count=2)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication Successful!")
except:
    print("Error during authentication! :(")
    
mentions = api.mentions_timeline()
pattern = r'([0-9]+.*[-+*/%].*[0-9]+)+' 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def check_mentions(api, since_id):
    logger.info("Collecting mentions... ")
    new_since_id = since_id
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline, since_id=since_id).items():
        match = re.search(pattern, tweet.text)
        equation = tweet.text[match.start():match.end()] 
        new_since_id = max(tweet.id, new_since_id)
        
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
            continue
        
        if match:
            ans = eval(tweet.text[match.start():match.end()]) 
            api.update_status(
                status=f"The answer to {str(equation)} is {ans}. ",
                in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
        elif not match:
            api.update_status(
                status=f"Hello! \n\nIt worked! \nYay! ^-^ \n\n (You said: \"{tweet.text}\".)",
                in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id) 
        
    return new_since_id

def main():
    since_id = 1
    while True:
        since_id = check_mentions(api, since_id)
        logger.info("Waiting... ")
        wait(15) 
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("Running script... ")
    wait(1) 
    main()
    
# for m in mentions:
#     api.update_status(f"@{m.user.screen_name} Hello! \nYou said: \n{m.text}", m.id)
#     wait(15)
```

When I run this, I get an error stating, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'`  on the `eval()` function (`equation = tweet.text[match.start():match.end()]`). I have researched this and how to index tweet text (with Tweepy). I'm confused as to why I get a `NoneType` error if I have a function directly above the `eval()` function. Shouldn't this catch that? Why does this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`re.search` returns a `NoneType` when it doesn't find a match. You should check the return value before using it, like this:

```
match = re.search(pattern, tweet.text)
if match:
    equation = tweet.text[match.start():match.end()]
```

Comment: I thought that, when there is no match, it would return False, and when there _is_ a match, it would return True. Now that I understand, I'm still not sure what to do because this script (essentially a copy of [Real Python's](https://realpython.com/twitter-bot-python-tweepy/#how-to-make-a-twitter-bot-in-python-with-tweepy) script) is checking my mentions timeline. So should I create a function/if statement to handle this error? My thinking is I shouldn't get any errors if there is no match, the script should just continue. Could you please help me understand why it doesn't? Thanks!

Comment: To know for sure, look at the documentation for the method - here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search ; In this case, the `re.search` method returns `None` if it doesn't find a match. You can verify this by (1) set a breakpoint on that line, (2) examine the contents of `pattern`, (3) examine the contents of `tweet.text`, (4) ascertain whether they match, (5) step over the statement to execute it, (6) examine the contents of `match` where it will either hold a `match` object or be `None`.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I forgot about those "breakpoint" things... What do they do again (I never really understood what they did, hence the reason I had never really used them)? Also, if it finds `None`, then I need it to do something. This is because every Tweet (where I'm mentioned) won't have a match, so I need to make sure it does something instead of returning an Error message when this happens. I still need to know what breakpoints do (I've searched it and I'm still a little confused, I know it essentially pauses the program, but does it return anything? Does it continue after a while?) ...

Comment: What IDE are you using? Look at the docs to see how to do debugging. Using the debugger to step through code and inspect variables is a great way to understand code. Also, if you want to improve the quality of your code, check out unit testing.